# Finding lower bound in multiset<pair<int,int> > in c++

Tags: c++, c++14, std

I'm storing the value and index in the stl multiset in c++. Now I want to find the highest index of lower bound value of a given value. For example if the set consists of {(2,1),(3,4),(4,2),(5,5),(5,6),(6,3)}  and now given value is 5, answer is 6, because lower bound of 5 will be 5 and the highest index is 6. How do i modify the lower_bound function to return the above?

I tried to insert (5,0) into the multiset and used the find function took the previous one as answer, but didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say, `lower bound value of a given value` what exactly do you mean? You can give the lower bound of a value in a collection but only if the value is comparable to the values contained. `int` is however not comparable to `pair<int, int>`.

Comment: By lower bound value of a given value in meant maximum of first value of the pairs in the multiset that is lesser than given value.

Comment: Then shouldn't this be a `multimap<int, int>` instead, so you can compare keys efficiently, as that is what seems to be intended? But I see how that would not give you indices.

Comment: What's wrong with just `set.insert(make_pair(5,0))`? What's your specific problem in which the find function has anything to do with inserting? These seem like totally unrelated bits of information stuck into the question and I don't know what your actual problem is.

Comment: You should avoid ambiguities in your question. Highest **index** is 6: what is your definition of an index. To me an index would the offset from the beginning of the multiset which cannot be the case because maximum index would be 5. Also, you said that lower bound of 5 will be 5. Which 5 are you referring to? To avoid such ambiguities, it would have been preferable that in your example, you use something like `(5, 11), (5, 17), (6, 9)` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't take lower bound (5,0) instead take lower bound of (6, -inf) and then take the returned iterator to the previous value as such.

```
int get_last_pos(x)
    auto it = map.lower_bound(make_pair(x + 1, -INF))
    assert(it != map.begin())
    it--;
    assert(it.first == x) 
    return it.second;
```

Comment: There is no `-INF` for `int` though so I guess it should check that (and not by assert as it could be contained legally)?

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks for the answer. For -INF i used INT_MIN

Comment: @k.b.shyam lower bound of `x` in that set was meant to be first value `not smaller`, so it could be greater, which would trigger the second assert. Or did I misunderstand your intention?